# Android: Master/Detail Flow on tablet

Tags: android

I've created application using master detail flow. I have custom `ListView` and `FrameLayout` as container to show detail of selected items from `ListView`. Everythig's fine but my detail is shown after onClick on ListView item. I would like to show detail of first item in `ListView` automatically after activity is created (sth. like android Settings activity). How should I do that? Thank you for response and your help.

Comment: Can you post the relevant code please?

Comment: I have followed this tutorial http://www.kaloer.com/making-your-app-tablet-friendly-3-steps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put your Fragment directly on onCreate() on the FrameLayout.

```
FragmentActivity frag = new FragmentActivity();
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(frag, details).commit();
```

and than always replace() via FragmentManager...